# How to left_join() two datasets but only select specific columns from one of the datasets?

Tags: r, select, dplyr, left-join, tidyverse

Here are two datasets: (this is fake data)

```r
library(tidyverse)
myfruit <- tibble(fruit_name = c("apple", "pear", "banana", "cherry"),
                  number = c(2, 4, 6, 8))

fruit_info <- tibble(fruit_name = c("apple", "pear", "banana", "cherry"),
                     colour = c("red", "green", "yellow", "d.red"),
                     batch_number = c(4, 4, 4, 4),
                     type = c("gala", "conference", "cavendish", "bing"),
                     weight = c(10, 11, 12, 13),
                     age_days = c(20, 22, 24, 16))

> myfruit
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  fruit_name number
  <chr>       <dbl>
1 apple           2
2 pear            4
3 banana          6
4 cherry          8

> fruit_info
# A tibble: 4 x 6
  fruit_name colour batch_number type       weight age_days
  <chr>      <chr>         <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>    <dbl>
1 apple      red               4 gala           10       20
2 pear       green             4 conference     11       22
3 banana     yellow            4 cavendish      12       24
4 cherry     d.red             4 bing           13       16
```

I want to use the `dplyr::left_join()` function to combine `myfruit` and `fruit_info` together, but I only want "batch_number" and "type" columns from `fruit_info`.

I know I can do this:

```r
new_myfruit <- left_join(myfruit, fruit_info, by = "fruit_name") %>%
  select(fruit_name, number, batch_number, type)

# OR

new_myfruit <- left_join(myfruit, fruit_info, by = "fruit_name") %>%
  select(-colour, -weight, -age_days)
```

But if I had many more columns in `fruit_info` and I had to type in many column names into the `select()` function it would be very time-consuming. So, is there a more efficient way to do this?

**Edit:**

I've seen examples online where you can do something like this:

```r
new_myfruits  <- left_join(myfruit,
                           fruit_info %>% select(batch_number, type),
                           by = "fruit_name")
```

But I get an error which says:

```r
# Error: Join columns must be present in data.
#  x Problem with `fruit_name`.
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

I would appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. You can combine `select()` with `contains()` and in the last function add the tags you want to extract, so there is no need of setting each name individually or by column number. Here the code:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
newdf <- left_join(myfruit, fruit_info, by = "fruit_name") %>%
  select(contains(c('fruit','number','type')))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  fruit_name number batch_number type      
  <chr>       <dbl>        <dbl> <chr>     
1 apple           2            4 gala      
2 pear            4            4 conference
3 banana          6            4 cavendish 
4 cherry          8            4 bing
```

Comment: Thanks, this works :) But do you know what I'm doing wrong here:  `new_myfruits  <- left_join(myfruit, fruit_info %>% select(batch_number, type), by = "fruit_name")`

Comment: @Karima Hi Kari, try setting the `select()` outside the join! Let me know if that works!

Comment: @Karima Or try this `left_join(myfruit,fruit_info %>% select(contains(c('fruit','number','type'))),by = "fruit_name")`

Comment: @Karima Fantastic, also a great question +1

Answer (score 3):

I believe you're getting that error because your select statement does not include "fruit_name", so it can't match on that column. Try `new_myfruits  <- left_join(myfruit, fruit_info %>% select(fruit_name, batch_number, type), by = "fruit_name")` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Does this work:

```
> myfruit %>% left_join(
+   fruit_info %>% select(1,3,4)
+ )
Joining, by = "fruit_name"
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  fruit_name number batch_number type      
  <chr>       <dbl>        <dbl> <chr>     
1 apple           2            4 gala      
2 pear            4            4 conference
3 banana          6            4 cavendish 
4 cherry          8            4 bing      
>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) It's a good method but not what I'm looking for